# Calcular diferença em dias entre duas datas excluindo final de semana

Tags: javascript, lógica

Gostaria de saber como faz para calcular a diferença em dias entre duas data, **excluindo sábado e domingo**.

Tenho um campo no meu formulário onde pega a data atua, e outro onde o usuário seleciona uma data.

```
var hoje = new Date('04/07/2019')
var dataFinal = new Date('10/07/2019')
```

no formato DD/MM/AAAA

Comment: Como você quer calcular a diferença entre as datas e mostrá-las no formato `DD/MM/AAAA`? Não me faz muito sentido. Aliás:

Comment: Excluindo sabados e domingos e feriados da conta (dias úteis)?

Comment: @LuizFelipe acho que não fui bem claro, mas não é pra ser retornado no formato DD/MM/AAAA, a data inicial e final é que são nesse formato, ele deverá retornar um inteiro, desculpa pelo o equívoco

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento apenas sábado e demingo

Answer (score 0):

f1 = diferença e retorna quando acaba.
param = data inicial;
param2 = data final;
param3 = dia da semana do primeiro parametro.

```js
var hoje = new Date();
var limite = 14;
var data = hoje.getDate();
function diferenca(param,param2,param3) {
    this.dia_feira = 0;
    this.day = param3.getDay();
    for (f0=param;f0<=param2;f0++) {
        if (this.day !== 0 && this.day !== 6) {
            this.dia_feira += 1;
        }
        if (this.day < 6) {
            this.day += 1;
        } else {
            this.day = 0;
        }
    }
    return this.dia_feira;
}
alert(diferenca(data,limite,hoje));
```

retorna 5;

Se vc quer algo avançado: 
https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

Tem função extras.